# Running a self decrypting base64 powershelll script locally with powershell -file /path/to/ps1

Tags: powershell, base64

I want to keep my powershell scripts on my local server in base64 but when run from schtasks or locally using powershell -file /path/to/ps1 they self decode. Is this possible??

I tried:

function Decode { $data = 'base 64 script'

[System.Text.Encoding]
::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))}

Decode

This does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the driver for this? I used once the `-EncodedCommand` as suggested but this was because I was generating my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least two options for this situation. One option is to send the base64 encoded command to Powershell.exe using the `-EncodedCommand` parameter. The second option is to create your decoding script to accept another script that contains the base64 encoded command as a parameter value.

---

**Option 1: Passing the Encoded Command**

This assumes your base64 encoded command is a string version of your PowerShell commands formatted using UTF-16LE character encoding (Unicode). Let's also assume that you have a script called `Encoded.ps1` that contains your base64 encoded command. With the prerequisites met, you can do the following:

```
Powershell.exe -EncodedCommand (Get-Content Encoded.ps1)
```

---

**Option 2: Running a Decode Script Against the Encoded Script**

The unicode requirement does not matter in this case (you can use ANSI if you like). You just need to know your original command string encoding so you can properly decode it. We will assume ASCII character set. Let's also assume that `Encoded.ps1` contains your base64 encoded command.

First, let's create the decode script called Decode.ps1.

```
# Decode.ps1
param([string]$FilePath)

$64EncodedData = Get-Content $FilePath  
$DecodedData = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($64EncodedData))

& ([scriptblock]::Create($DecodedData))
```

Second, let's run the Powershell.exe command to decode `Encoded.ps1` and execute the decoded command.

```
Powershell.exe -File Decoded.ps1 -FilePath Encoded.ps1
```

The code above is not intended to display the contents of the decoded commands but rather execute the decoded commands. `$FilePath` is the path to your `Encoded.ps1` file, which contains a base64 encoded string from an ASCII encoded character set. You can change to whichever encoding applies to your situation in the `Decode.ps1` file. `$DecodedData` contains the original command strings. Finally, a script block is created containing `$DecodedData` and then called with the call operator `&`.

Comment: Thanks AdminOfThings, very helpful. I will mark your answer as the right one! Much appreciated